# VS Code crashing with "Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled" after update to PopOS 22

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, crash, webgl

Since updating PopOS from 21 to 22, VS Code crashes on launch.

I have tried running `code --verbose` and it gives the following output

```
$ code --verbose
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.778Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.779Z] from: /usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.779Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-keytar': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': 'ea2e3322-8c40-448d-b84a-fd3bb0308659',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  __sandbox: false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  logsPath: '/home/<myuser>/.config/Code/logs/20220428T153703'
}
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.781Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.782Z] Resolved machine identifier: 79645325f53065167905640954119fe409b9a603fcdad076cc163d250d6f9a4b
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.782Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.797Z] StorageMainService: creating global storage
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.798Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.798Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.799Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    workspace: { id: '5ef82008e1d2d6fc517c59a71af1e304', uri: [g] },
    exists: true
  }
]
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.800Z] IPC Object URL: Registered new channel vscode:575816a7-c5fe-48a0-9bfb-3bd3d1577c92.
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.800Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 1 display(s) { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 141, width: 1920, height: 976 }
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.800Z] window#validateWindowState: 1 monitor working area { x: 0, y: 32, width: 1920, height: 976 }
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.800Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 141, width: 1920, height: 976 }
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.857Z] StorageMainService: creating workspace storage (5ef82008e1d2d6fc517c59a71af1e304)
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.858Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 1, emptyToRestore: 0, emptyToOpen: 0)
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.860Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.861Z] update#setState idle
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.861Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[6997:0428/153703.936491:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153703.936509:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[main 2022-04-28T14:37:03.984Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[6997:0428/153704.137675:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.137692:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[6997:0428/153704.319363:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.319377:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[7074:0428/153704.332285:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for swiftshader
[7074:0428/153704.332407:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[6997:0428/153704.429684:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.429700:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
[7078:0428/153704.438318:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for swiftshader
[7078:0428/153704.438393:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[6997:0428/153704.534908:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.534922:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[7082:0428/153704.543009:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for swiftshader
[7082:0428/153704.543119:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[6997:0428/153704.639089:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.639103:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[7086:0428/153704.643143:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for disabled
[7086:0428/153704.643248:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[6997:0428/153704.754902:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.754917:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 7 time(s)
[7090:0428/153704.759180:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for disabled
[7090:0428/153704.759311:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[6997:0428/153704.878321:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153704.878337:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 8 time(s)
[7094:0428/153704.882875:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for disabled
[7094:0428/153704.882964:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[6997:0428/153705.019793:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[6997:0428/153705.019808:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1321)] The GPU process has crashed 9 time(s)
[6997:0428/153705.019816:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
/dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
Server response:
/dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
Server response:
```

Slack is also behaving in the same way, crashing with the same error.

I am able to get VS Code running by passing `--no-zygote` and `--no-sandbox` flags

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
Running it with `--no-sandbox` flag works, but many extensions are disabled.

I tried removing it from Pop!_Shop and instead of installing the .deb version I was using I installed the flatpak one.

With that version, it starts fine. I needed to install the extensions again, and most of them worked. I had problems with Pylance extension, because some files were already created from the previous installation.
I removed all the `~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code` folder contents (moved them to a backup location in case the .deb version works again in the future) and installed everything again.

So far, it's better that not having some extensions that would not allow me to follow function definitions for example. But I found problems like not being able to choose from all available pyenv interpreters, and the dialog for browsing files seems to be different and more limited than the one I remember from the .deb version.

So depending on your needs, you may consider installing the flatpak version if that works for you.

If there is any way for getting the .deb version working again I'm also interested in knowing about it.

EDIT: Finally I removed the flatpak version as well and installed the latest .deb from the vscode site manually: https://code.visualstudio.com/
With this newer version everything works as expected, the drawback is not having an official Pop Os package.